# npm package install issues

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm, package

I'm having a problem with npm.

When I install packages they will go to the `node_modules` folder, but instead of the package assets being in one folder it puts them outside of that folder.

In the express folder, all of the folders in that are supposed to be inside, but instead, they are outside of it.  This also happens with other packages I try to install. I have tried creating a test project, but the same thing happened,

And I also tried uninstalling node and npm, and it is still happening.

Comment: Are you sure you need to install the package in that location and not global? using `npm install --global myPackage` installs the package globally, making it available outside the directory you are in when you executed the install.

Comment: If you set custom path of installation NPM packages locally then this issue is arise. Please check for solution: https://gist.github.com/HaykoKoryun/cdfb96894dee766381ed

Comment: try sudo npm install, it will works, its because permission issue

Comment: hey thanks for the responses! So I did try your suggestions, but I still get the same thing happening where the dependencies want make another node_modules folder in there own folders

Answer (score 0):

You sure it's not dependencies?

NPM will install additional packages if you need them, and place them in root of the `node_modules` folder so that other modules later can use the same if they need them.

After running (edit: `npm init` first to get package.json in the root of the project) `npm install express --save` on empty project, I end up with

[image: express]

PS. Apologies if I misused terms, I'm still quiet new to node and npm

Comment: Hey Miroslav this was the problem I had what node version are you using?

Comment: This isn't a problem, that is the expected behaviour, this happens on every computer I've worked on. However node is v5.0.0 and npm is v3.3.6

Answer (score 0):

I found out what happened it was because of node v5.1.1 that the package folders were saving outside of the express folder once I went back to node v4.2.3 it made a node_modules folder inside the express folder.

Thanks again for everyones help